# Padding Zero to left in Varchar

Tags: postgresql, varchar

I have a column `tattoo` that is `varchar(20)` type. I want this to be padded left with 3 zeros. N009 should become 000N009.

`to_char(integer/double precsion/int/timestamp,text)` but is there any way we could do this to `varchar`?

Casting `varchar(20)` to `integer` did not worked either. Some of my code added below:

```
select tattoo,to_char(tattoo,'0000FM')::varchar as tm from animals where soc_code = 'AURO' limit 100
select tattoo,to_char(tattoo::integer,'0000FM')::varchar as tm from animals where soc_code = 'AURO' limit 100
select tattoo,to_char(cast(tattoo as integer),'0000FM')::varchar as tm from animals where soc_code = 'AURO' limit 100
```

They both throw errors saying invalid input syntax for integer and function_to_char does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [LPAD()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

```
select LPAD( tattoo, 7, '0' )
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want this to be padded left with 3 zeros. N009 should become 000N009.

You may be overthinking this. Just [concatenate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
SELECT '000' || tatoo;
```

If `tatoo` is `NULL`, so is the result.

Comment: I do agree that is easy way. However in '000' || tattoo the result will always be 3 zeros at the front. If the tattoo is KN009 then it should become 00KN009. If tattoo is JKN009 then result should be 0JKN009.

Comment: @TechPathi: I understand. But that's not what the question is asking for. Use [`lpad()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) for that, like the other answer suggests.